# Creating boundaries around lines based on attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, administrative-boundaries, standard-license-level

I am trying to create polygons around lines within another polygon based on a lines attribute[image: Example]

Basically from this I want three boundaries within this boundary for each section of line. I have been scouring for solutions but have yet to find one.

Unfortunately I only have an ArcGIS standard license.

Comment: Use small size raster and Euclidian allocation to your streets. Convert raster to polygon and clip it by big polygon. The smaller the cell raster the finer result

Answer (score 1):

If you can download QGIS, you can create voronoi polygons or convex/concave hulls (as suggested by DPSSpatial). I would dissolve your line features by the groupings shown in your graphic. Then I would clip the output with the polygon representing the aggregate boundary. If not, you may be able to create a large buffer distance on the line features so there are no holes in your polygons (dissolve within the tool on shared line attribute), perform integrate, and clip. Third, if you can download census blocks that are small enough to fit your line features you can spatial join them with lines IDs, dissolve, clip.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a convex / concave hull solution?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I think convex hull would be the same work flow in terms of the initial polygon creation but you would still need a dissolve and clip and QGIS as these features are only available with the advance license in ArcMap.

Comment: Convex Hull 'based on input field' would do this I think...? But I might not understand his data enough...